# Monte Carlo / Gambler's Fallacy in fair coin toss: why bet on Tails after 26 consecutive Heads

Tags: mathematical-statistics

given a **fair** coin that tossed Heads [26 consecutive times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy#Monte_Carlo_Casino), we need to decide whether gamble on Tails and provide a logical statistical explanation.

Since this is a fair coin and the probability of each event is 1/2:

- after 26 consecutive Heads, the probability of Tails remains equal to the probability of Heads (1/2).
- the probability of every sequence appearing is equally very low 7.45e^-9: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH**H** has the exact same probability as HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH**T** which has the exact same probability as HTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHT

Nevertheless, my biased human intuition tells me to bet on tails. What is the correct theoretical foundation? ..or is this just a common misconception of chance?

Appendix:

- simulating 10,000 tosses I observed maximum of 12 consecutive Heads

Thank you

Comment: Since the tosses are independent, what happened in the 26 previous tosses does not impact the probability of a tail in the next toss.

Comment: If anything betting on tails is the only answer that you cannot really justify. Betting on heads through an evidence of bias argument, or betting on no impact through a gamblers fallacy argument are the only real two bets you can justify.

Comment: So what is the rational argument to change my biased human intuition that tells me to bet on tails simply because "after 26 consecutive Heads, the coin must toss Tails very soon"?

Comment: The rational attitude is to question the fairness assumption. (Even though [coin tossing is always fair!](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/7320273)) Or the "observation" of 26 tails in a row.

Comment: I agree. But let's assume we know for certain the coin is fair. What is the probability of the 27th toss to be Tails in order for the coin to be fair? Please let me know if I explained myself.

Comment: The (joint) probability for having 27 tail tosses in a row is $1/2^{27}$, just like the probability of any fixed sequence. The marginal probability of having a tail on the 27th toss remains $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

The key points here are that we are told (1) that the coin is fair and (2) that each flip is completely random and independent from the previous flip. If these two conditions are met, then the probability of the next flip being tails is 1/2. If the conditions are NOT met, then the probability is unlikely to be 1/2.

If we didn't know if the coin was fair, and we observed 26 heads in a row, suspiciousness should be fully aroused. This would be very strong evidence that the coin is not fair. Betting on heads would be the thing to do. (In your example, we assume the coin is fair so this does not apply here)

As Xi'an commented, the fact that each toss is independent means that the "history" is complete irrelevant. If the flips are not independent, then the history could give us information about the next flip. (Again this does not apply to your question because we are assuming independent flips.)

Comment: Good point. This makes me think that knowing for certain the coin is fair, then at some point we need to observe at some Tails. Therefore, there must be a way to calculate the probability of T for the next tosses in order for the coin to be fair. What do you think?

Comment: You aren't guaranteed to observe a tails. The probability of observing all heads under the assumptions of the problem tends to one as the number of flips tends to infinity. But, this does not mean you *must* observe a tails.